# How do "apt-get clean" and "apt-get clean all" differ?

Tags: command-line, apt

What, if anything, is the difference between this command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

And this command:

```
sudo apt-get clean all
```

On my Lubuntu 12.04 system, simulating these commands reveals their behavior to be exactly the same:

```
ek@Apok:~$ apt-get -s clean
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
ek@Apok:~$ apt-get -s clean all
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
ek@Apok:~$
```

Is there ever any difference in `apt-get`'s behavior with `clean` and `clean all`? If so, what is the difference, under what circumstances is it relevant, and how should I choose between the two? If there is no difference, then why does `clean all` exist?

If they're the same, then `clean all` would still make sense if `clean` could ordinarily take a package name as an argument. But this is not the case--attempting to pass a package name to `clean` doesn't alter `clean`'s behavior at all, the whole cache still gets deleted:

```
ek@Apok:~$ apt-get -s clean nano
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
```

This does make me wonder, though, if perhaps `clean all` *doesn't* really exist (and that what's happening is that `all` is ignored, just as `nano` was in the above example).

Is `clean all` just an urban legend?

Comment: "Is clean all just an urban legend?" Yes, sir.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

In

```
sudo apt-get clean all
```

`all` is just ignored, like anything else you append after `clean`.

It's the same with for example

```
sudo apt-get clean my room
```

Comment: Is (or was) there any documentation that recommended `clean all`? How did the practice of running `sudo apt-get clean all` arise? Did the behavior used to be different? Or is running `clean all` just a confusion, perhaps arising from somewhat similar `make` syntax?

Comment: I've never seen any documentation recommending `apt-get clean all`. I guess it's a confusion with `make` or something similar.

Comment: When I search for `apt-get clean all` on Google, there are 48,900 results (though, admittedly, the first two are for this question). On the other hand, the manual page hasn't said anything about it, and I can't find any official sources that recommend using it. I'd like to know more about how this arose...but I suspect that might take considerable time and effort.

Comment: A messy room/desk gnawing on your subconscious, @EliahKagan? :P

Comment: The affectation of adding the "all" is most likely a hangover from "yum clean all"

Comment: guys what about `man apt-get`  ?

Comment: +1 for `sudo apt-get clean my room` XD

Comment: Tried to clean my room… didn't do anything :(