# aptitude (apt-get) always crashes

Tags: 12.10, apt, firefox

I'm using Ubuntu Quantal. I've recently updated and now my kernel is `3.5.0-23-generic`.

After upgrade my NVIDIA driver stopped working... no problem! I re-installed it and now it works.

Now I started my Ubuntu, everything is just fine but:

- Firefox keeps crashing (always! different timeframes, but always crashes, sometimes 10 sometimes 60 sec after run);
- when I run `apt-get install [something]` I get this:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install curl
  Reading package lists... Done
  ```

When I run update **Software Updater** I get this:

> Task cannot be monitored or controlled
>
> The connection to the daemon was lost. Most likely the background daemon crashed.
>
> **Details**
>
> It seems that the daemon died.

If it helps, I can confess that I had like 2-3 hard reset on my PC recently if you think that could cause such problem. Entered recovery mode, selected `fsck`, waited a lot, I saw nothing, no change, no message, no progress, waited like 90 mins there, re-hard resetted.

What do you suggest? What could be the source of problem? What should I check/fix?

Answer (score 6):

I found out solution, these commands fixes everything:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -fr /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

I saved above commands as an sh file and I always run it when it crashes again.
Hope it helps you also.

Comment: Could you explain the commands, especially line three? Is the first line not superfluous, given line two? Thx.

Comment: Line two is redundant: http://askubuntu.com/a/144224/16023